# Inno setup registry

Tags: windows, registry, inno-setup

What can I add to the win registry so that the explorer context menu, when you right click on a file, gains an entry that calls "\path\to\exe" "path\to\this\file\you\right\clicked\on"? If that's possible to be done in Inno setup easily, could you possibly provide me with some examples? (As well as get rid of the registry key upon uninstall)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did in MSBuild Launch Pad (http://msbuildlaunchpad.codeplex.com/) is like this,

1. Your application must handle arguments from Windows Explorer properly.
2. The following registry key are used by the installer,

   [Registry]

   Root: HKCR; Subkey: SystemFileAssociations.sln\shell\MSBuild; ValueType: string; Flags: uninsdeletekey deletekey; ValueName: Icon; ValueData: """{app}\MSBuild_APPICON.ico"""

   Root: HKCR; Subkey: SystemFileAssociations.csproj\shell\MSBuild; ValueType: string; ValueData: """{app}\MSBuild_APPICON.ico"""; Flags: uninsdeletekey deletekey; ValueName: Icon

   Root: HKCR; Subkey: SystemFileAssociations.vbproj\shell\MSBuild; ValueType: string; ValueData: """{app}\MSBuild_APPICON.ico"""; Flags: uninsdeletekey deletekey; ValueName: Icon

   Root: HKCR; Subkey: SystemFileAssociations.vcxproj\shell\MSBuild; ValueType: string; ValueData: """{app}\MSBuild_APPICON.ico"""; Flags: uninsdeletekey deletekey; ValueName: Icon

   Root: HKCR; Subkey: SystemFileAssociations.oxygene\shell\MSBuild; ValueType: string; ValueData: """{app}\MSBuild_APPICON.ico"""; Flags: uninsdeletekey deletekey; ValueName: Icon

   Root: HKCR; Subkey: SystemFileAssociations.shfbproj\shell\MSBuild; ValueType: string; ValueData: """{app}\MSBuild_APPICON.ico"""; Flags: uninsdeletekey deletekey; ValueName: Icon

   Root: HKCR; Subkey: SystemFileAssociations.ccproj\shell\MSBuild; ValueType: string; ValueData: """{app}\MSBuild_APPICON.ico"""; Flags: uninsdeletekey deletekey; ValueName: Icon
   Root: HKCR; Subkey: SystemFileAssociations.proj\shell\MSBuild; ValueType: string; ValueData: """{app}\MSBuild_APPICON.ico"""; Flags: uninsdeletekey deletekey; ValueName: Icon

   Root: HKCR; Subkey: SystemFileAssociations.sln\shell\MSBuild\command; ValueType: string; ValueData: """{app}\MSBuildLaunchPad.exe"" ""%1"""; Flags: uninsdeletekey deletekey

   Root: HKCR; Subkey: SystemFileAssociations.csproj\shell\MSBuild\command; ValueType: string; ValueData: """{app}\MSBuildLaunchPad.exe"" ""%1"""; Flags: uninsdeletekey deletekey

   Root: HKCR; Subkey: SystemFileAssociations.vbproj\shell\MSBuild\command; ValueType: string; ValueData: """{app}\MSBuildLaunchPad.exe"" ""%1"""; Flags: uninsdeletekey deletekey

   Root: HKCR; Subkey: SystemFileAssociations.vcxproj\shell\MSBuild\command; ValueType: string; ValueData: """{app}\MSBuildLaunchPad.exe"" ""%1"""; Flags: uninsdeletekey deletekey

   Root: HKCR; Subkey: SystemFileAssociations.oxygene\shell\MSBuild\command; ValueType: string; ValueData: """{app}\MSBuildLaunchPad.exe"" ""%1"""; Flags: uninsdeletekey deletekey

   Root: HKCR; Subkey: SystemFileAssociations.shfbproj\shell\MSBuild\command; ValueType: string; ValueData: """{app}\MSBuildLaunchPad.exe"" ""%1"""; Flags: uninsdeletekey deletekey

   Root: HKCR; Subkey: SystemFileAssociations.ccproj\shell\MSBuild\command; ValueType: string; ValueData: """{app}\MSBuildLaunchPad.exe"" ""%1"""; Flags: uninsdeletekey deletekey

   Root: HKCR; Subkey: SystemFileAssociations.proj\shell\MSBuild\command; ValueType: string; ValueData: """{app}\MSBuildLaunchPad.exe"" ""%1"""; Flags: uninsdeletekey deletekey